# Import CSV file into MySQL table using php LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import an CSV file into MySQL table.My code is

```
$sql1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$this->filePath' INTO TABLE xyz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS";
mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql1) or die("Problem:". mysqli_error($this->conn));
```

When the code is executed the script give me an error like

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 2"

Comment: Try `TERMINATED BY '\\n'`

Comment: I tried this but the error is same

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\`. Try this

```
$sql1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$this->filePath' INTO TABLE xyz FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Comment: Will you try edited answer? change `IGNORE 1 ROWS` to `IGNORE 1 LINES`

Comment: The only problem shows is in  '\\n'  except this there is no problem...

Comment: The issue is in `ENCLOSED BY` Are sure you want to ENCLOSED your data WITH "\" ? Its normally `"` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html